# Php read error from file

Tags: php, html

I have this :

```
     echo '


     <div id="headlineatas">
     <br>
     <div id="adsground">
     <br><br><br>
     <p align="center"><span style="font-size: 44px;"> Language Selection </span></p>
<table height="400" width="1024">
        <tr>
        <td>


        <center><a href="index.php?lang=en" id="language1">
    <img title="English" src="/img/language_selection/us_first.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/us.png"\' onmouseout="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/us_first.png"\' />
</a>

            </center>

        </td>
        <td>

        <center><a href="index.php?lang=ro" id="language2">
    <img title="Romanian" src="/img/language_selection/ro_first.png" onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/ro.png"\' onmouseout="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/ro_first.png"\' />
</a>


        </center>

        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>



</div></div></center>
```

I have en error like : `syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'` in but i don't understand what is the problem , or when i modify it , the on mouse over code doesn't work . Where i go wrong?

Comment: The `echo '` at the very top of your posted code, is that actually part of it? What is your **full code**?

Comment: why echo the above, it' pure html so why not just break out of your php and render it normally.  You won't get into a backslash nightmare then

Comment: If that's your actual code and I don't know how you're using it, remove the `echo '`. If you're using it as an iframe, then replace it with `echo "` then add `";` at the very end of your "posted" code. Theoretically it could work, but then you may have to `escape` double quotes.

Comment: @Pete Yes I'm aware of that. See my new comment just above ;-)

Comment: wow second person today I've seen using `center` tags, they must be making a comeback!

Comment: @Pete There are a few possible scenarios to fix this. One of which is to simply add `<?php ?>` at the very top, delete the `echo '` and run it as regular HTML under the tags.

Comment: @Fred That would be the way I would go as it looks like plain html

Comment: @Pete I use the `<center>` tag too at times, it's a quick and dirty way. However it doesn't always work if set inside a div that has CSS assigned to it, with an overtaking `text-align:left;` or other.

Comment: @Pete Yep. It's definitely the `echo '` bit that's fouling things up. Unless there's something I am not getting and is a morning **quiz**! lol

Comment: just for reference, the center tag has been deprecated since 1998 (html4) and is now obsolete in html5

Comment: @Pete Yeah I knew that, but **why** does it still work in some of the stuff I do? lol! Meaning, that I still use it at times instead of adding it to `<p...` or `<div align` **"Deprecated"**... I don't quite get that word. Wha?..... there's no place left to SqueeEEEeeeze that bit of code into the Web browser source code? lol nope... I just don't get that. Oh well, no biggie. *"C'est la vie"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax in mouseover and mouseout code:

Replace :

```
onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/us.png"\'
```

Withe the below code:

```
onmouseover="this.src=\'/img/language_selection/us.png\'"
                                                      ^^^
```

Here the single quota is outside on the double quota. so change it every mouseover and mouseout events.

Comment: +1 But not only `onmouseover`, also `onmouseout` and any other `Event Attributes` you may have.

Comment: @gmo You are right. I am updating my answer.